# How can add a 3D text on each cluster's center to show its size (number of points) using pcl

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I have a mini task in PCL related to color based region growing segmentation. The goal of the task is to cluster the cloud based on color and show the cluster size or number of points contain each cluster at its center.

The clustering part I have done already, but how can I do the second part?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be using the `pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer` and its method `.addText3D()`

Here's its header from the [cl::visualization::PCLVisualizer Class Reference](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html#a81eef75fbd6f48f851c5847b75e1f59c):

```
template<typename PointT > 
bool pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addText3D   (   
        const std::string &     text,
        const PointT &      position,
        double      textScale = 1.0,
        double      r = 1.0,
        double      g = 1.0,
        double      b = 1.0,
        const std::string &     id = "",
        int     viewport = 0 
    )
```